# Facebook ads not served via Google DFP mediation in Android?

Tags: android, ios, google-dfp, facebook-audience-network, mobile-ad-mediation

We are currently working on implementing Ad-Exchange mediation from Facebook audience network into our app.

We are following the guidelines for iOS and Android. In iOS version of the app, We are getting both Google and Facebook ads(Banner and Interstitial) from DFP server with yield groups, but the same is not working in Android.

We have added the latest Facebook Audience Network SDK and Facebook adapter to our Android project and have tried the following test cases

1. Added test devices to Publisher Ad Request
2. Added device hash ID to Facebook Ad settings
3. Increased CPM value in Yield group(Facebook)
4. Added android test device AAID in facebook audience network dashboard
5. Logged in Facebook tester account with Facebook App and test device browser

In Android, we are only getting google ads from DFP server with line items, but not from yield group (Facebook yield partner). On the other hand, we are able to get the ads directly from the Facebook audience network using Facebook SDK. Could you kindly check to see if there is anything that has to be done to get FB ads served through DFP?

We have added implementation `com.facebook.android:audience-network-sdk:5.0.0` implementation `com.google.ads.mediation:facebook:5.0.0.0` dependencies on `build.gradle(app)`.